# Error using redirect in pylons

Tags: python, pylons

Using Pylons verson 1.0:
Working on the FormDemo example from the Pylons book:

http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/working-with-forms-and-validators.html

My controller has the following functions:

```
class FormtestController(BaseController):

    def form(self):
        return render('/simpleform.html')

    def submit(self):
        # Code to perform some action based on the form data
        # ...
        h.redirect_to(controller='formtest', action='result')

    def result(self):
        return 'Your data was successfully submitted.'
```

First I noticed that in the book the author indicates to import redirect_to you executing the following import:

```
from pylons.controllers.util import redirect_to
```

This seems to be incorrect, as redirect_to lives in the routes module so I changed it to this:

```
from routes import redirect_to
```

everything works fine, no more import error, but when I execute a form submit, i see the following traceback

---

```
h.redirect_to(controller='formtest', action='result')
target = url_for(*args, **kargs)
encoding = config.mapper.encoding
return getattr(self.__shared_state, name)
AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'mapper'
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
from pylons import url
from pylons.controllers.util import redirect

# ...
redirect(url(controller='formtest', action='result'))
```

You might be better off using the current [Pylons 1.0 documentation](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/1.0/) and the [QuickWiki tutorial](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/1.0/tutorials/quickwiki_tutorial/) updated for 1.0, among other references on the site.

Comment: To clarify, support for redirect_to (and url_for) has been deprecated in Pylons 0.97 and removed in Pylons 1.0.  The Pylons book was based on 0.97, so you may want to read http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/1.0/upgrading/

Comment: The QuickWiki page actually isn't fully updated for Pylons 1.0 either (it even references 0.97 in a few places).  You're best bet is to kind of loosely follow the directions while looking at the quickwiki source pulled from bitbucket - which works for 1.0.

Comment: That's really annoying that the book that is supposed to cover 1.1 is based on 0.97

Comment: @qliq this has really annoyed me too. i realized that the 1.1 is the book's documentation number -- but it's all for the 0.9.7 release, and  pylons is at 1.0.1, not 1.1.